# Matrix in Azure DevOps yaml pipeline: The pipeline is not valid

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

For our mobile app, I am trying to use matrix to set different pipeline values in Debug and Release:

```
jobs:
- job: Job_1
  displayName: .Net MAUI Job
  strategy:
    maxParallel: 2
    matrix: 
      Debug:
        BuildConfiguration: Debug
        ProvProfile: 'My_Testing_Profile.mobileprovision'
        CertSecureFile: 'ios_development.p12'
        CertPwd: $(IOSP12Password-testing)
      Release:
        BuildConfiguration: Release
        ProvProfile: 'My_Distribution_Profile.mobileprovision'
        CertSecureFile: 'ios_distribution.p12'
        CertPwd: $(IOSP12Password-distribution)
```

...

```
    - task: InstallAppleCertificate@2
      displayName: Install Apple Certificate
      inputs:
        certSecureFile: $(CertSecureFile)
        certPwd: $(CertPwd)
        setUpPartitionIdACLForPrivateKey: false
        deleteCert: false
        deleteCustomKeychain: false

    - task: InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1
      displayName: Install Testing Apple Provisioning Profile
      inputs:
        provisioningProfileLocation: 'secureFiles'
        provProfileSecureFile: $(ProvProfile)
```

...

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet publish ($(BuildConfiguration))'
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishWebProjects: false
    projects: 'My_MobileApp.sln'
    arguments: '-f:net6.0-ios -c:$(BuildConfiguration) -r ios-arm64 /p:ArchiveOnBuild=true /p:EnableAssemblyILStripping=false'
    zipAfterPublish: false
    modifyOutputPath: false
```

IOSP12Password-testing and IOSP12Password-distribution are variables set in the pipeline.

I am getting the following error:
There was a resource authorization issue: "The pipeline is not valid.

Job Job_1: Step InstallAppleCertificate input certSecureFile references secure file $(CertSecureFile) which could not be found. The secure file does not exist or has not been authorized for use.

Job Job_1: Step InstallAppleProvisioningProfile input provProfileSecureFile references secure file $(ProvProfile) which could not be found. The secure file does not exist or has not been authorized for use.

I suspect that CertPwd is also wrong.
I don't understand why it is not working, if there is no problem with BuildConfiguration at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure Devops Services now don't support using variable in secure file.
So if your profile and certificate files have already been added into the library-secure file, you need to directly write the name of the file into your yaml instead of variables.

If you do need the feature, you can directly report the [feature requests](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=22&entry=suggestion). That will allow you to directly interact with the appropriate engineering team and make it more convenient for the engineering team to collect and categorize your suggestions.

---

updates:

You could try to use '[condition sytax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)' here to repeat the two tasks with different hard code value, if you need to choose the value in runtime, you could use parameters, it should be something like this:

```
parameters:
- name: CertSecureFile
  values:
  - ios_development.p12
  - ios_distribution.p12
- name: ProvProfile
  values:
  - My_Testing_Profile.mobileprovision
  - My_Distribution_Profile.mobileprovision

stages:
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - job: Job_1
    displayName: .Net MAUI Job
    strategy:
      maxParallel: 2
      matrix: 
        Debug:
          BuildConfiguration: Debug
          ProvProfile: 'My_Testing_Profile.mobileprovision'
          CertSecureFile: 'ios_development.p12'
          CertPwd: $(IOSP12Password-testing)
        Release:
          BuildConfiguration: Release
          ProvProfile: 'My_Distribution_Profile.mobileprovision'
          CertSecureFile: 'ios_distribution.p12'
          CertPwd: $(IOSP12Password-distribution)
    steps: 
      - task: InstallAppleCertificate@2
        condition: eq('${{ parameters.CertSecureFile }}', 'ios_development.p12')
        displayName: Install Apple Certificate
        inputs:
          certSecureFile: ios_development.p12
          certPwd: $(CertPwd)
          setUpPartitionIdACLForPrivateKey: false
          deleteCert: false
          deleteCustomKeychain: false
      - task: InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1
        condition: eq('${{ parameters.ProvProfile }}', 'My_Testing_Profile.mobileprovision')
        displayName: Install Testing Apple Provisioning Profile
        inputs:
          provisioningProfileLocation: 'secureFiles'
          provProfileSecureFile: My_Testing_Profile.mobileprovision


      - task: InstallAppleCertificate@2
        condition: eq('${{ parameters.CertSecureFile }}', 'ios_distribution.p12')
        displayName: Install Apple Certificate
        inputs:
          certSecureFile: ios_distribution.p12
          certPwd: $(CertPwd)
          setUpPartitionIdACLForPrivateKey: false
          deleteCert: false
          deleteCustomKeychain: false
      - task: InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1
        condition: eq('${{ parameters.ProvProfile }}', 'My_Distribution_Profile.mobileprovision')
        displayName: Install Testing Apple Provisioning Profile
        inputs:
          provisioningProfileLocation: 'secureFiles'
          provProfileSecureFile: My_Distribution_Profile.mobileprovision
```

---

updates:

If you want to use template with parameters, you could put the repeated two jobs with two fixed value in two templates yaml in the same repo and branch.(here we name it for example, template1.yaml and template2.yaml)

Then you could try something like this:

```
steps:
- ${{ if and(eq(parameters.CertSecureFile, 'ios_development.p12'),eq(parameters.ProvProfile, 'My_Testing_Profile.mobileprovision')) }}:
  - template: template1.yaml
- ${{ else }}:
  - template: template2.yaml
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it is not what the question was about. The problem is that setting secure file names from variables in the pipeline does not work.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot hard-code the file names, as they depend on whether it is Debug or Release. So basically you are saying there is no solution currently...

Comment: Hi, you could try to use condition to repeat the task for two different hard code. Please kindly have a look. Much appreciate.

Comment: And this solution would not require using templates?

Comment: Hi David, I have updated the reply above, please kindly see whether it could do some help. Thanks.